# Changing Brush style for Scribble tool (fill) in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, illustrator-effects

I want a scribble effect (as if someone had taken a pencil and scribbled out this headline), and I can get the desired brush style (pictured here as the circle) when I draw, but not when I use the scribble tool to fill the rectangle.

[image]  When I change the brush to the desired style, it automatically applies it to the outer stroke of the shape, (so I know it is possible), but it won't allow me to change the style of the scribble that fills the box. Is there a workaround? Previously I had drawn a path and applied the brush, but it looked very unnatural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't boot CC 2020 at the moment. It's not impossible that Adobe changed things in "bleeding edge" versions...but..

---

... in CC2017 (or earlier)

## To apply the Scribble Effect

- Target the **fill* if you wish the Scribble to be applied the fill.
- Choose `Effect > Stylize > Scribble` from the menu and the **Scribble Options** dialog will pop up, and apply the effect the to selected object.
- Within the dialog window you can make any adjustments you want to the scribble itself.
- Click the **<kbd>OK</kbd>** button when you are happy.

---

## To alter the Scribble effect *after* it's applied...

- Look at the **Appearance Panel** (`Window > Appearance`)
- Expand the fill (or stroke) and click the `Scribble` item seen in the panel.
- This will open the **Scribble Options Dialog** window again where you can make further changes.

---

[image]

---

## To **alter the *style* of the strokes 
within the Scribble Effect**...

There's no direct way, in CC2017 at least, to directly alter the stroke appearance *within the effect itself*. The Scribble effect will *only* create simple, basic, strokes. There's no ability or method to apply something such as a brush stroke to the paths created by the effect while at the same time, keeping the effect "live" and editable.

However, you can expand the appearance to apply a brush stroke...

- Set the effect
- Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu. This will "bake in" the scribble and it'll no longer be adjustable.
- *Now* you can click a brush and it will be applied to the scribble paths...

[image]

---

## If the effect has been expanded...

Lastly, if the effect appearance has been *expanded* via the menu command `Object > Expand Appearance`, and all the lines are highlighted when you select the object... a la...

[image]

... Then there is no way to easily alter the effect any further. It is no longer a "live" effect in that case. The easiest solution for this is to *recreate* the original object/shape and then reapply the effect to the new object, deleting the expanded artwork.

---

<sub>These animations are using CC2017. There *may* be some visual differences in more recent versions of Illustrator. However, all the functionality should still be present in the options dialog window.</sub>

Comment: You can group the object and apply the stroke you wish on the group.

Comment: True @joojaa but that may come with other issues. For example, the subsequent stroke will *also* include the [object's outer path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyOOB.png), not merely the inner scribble paths.

Comment: yes but you can eliminta ethat with the scribble effect itself, but yes not entrely ideal. Again a reason for the delete/filter  effect

Comment: @joojaa I don't know how a user removes that boundary stroke via the effect itself. Perhaps that's something CC2019+ does? It doesn't appear possible in CC2017 or CS6.

Comment: If pathoverlap is negative and you have a stroke then the path gets deleted

Comment: Ya lost me, @joojaa .... `:)` Maybe they changed it in newer versions but a [negative path overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOMlw.png) doesn't seem to remove the bounding stroke if there's a stroke on the group. (that's CS6 now now a feature improvement in bleeding edge releases is entirely possible)

Comment: It must begin with a stroke thats visible. Yeah i know counter intuitive

Comment: Ahh.. tricky.. good to know though. Thanks.